# Javascript not working in chrome with a .php extension

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

I have a php page that calls a header ?php include 'inc/head.php'; ?.

In this header is a javascript function that I posted below. Everything works great in Firefox and even in IE(which is a miracle in itself.) However, in Chrome it does not work. It does work on a .html page but in the php pages nothing shows. Thanks so much in advanced.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
         var timeout = 500;
         var closetimer = 0;
         var ddmenuitem = 0;

         // open hidden layer
         function mopen(id) {
             // cancel close timer
             mcancelclosetime();

             // close old layer
             if (ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

             // get new layer and show it
             ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
             ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

         }
         // close showed layer
         function mclose() {
             if (ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
         }

         // go close timer
         function mclosetime() {
             closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
         }

         // cancel close timer
         function mcancelclosetime() {
             if (closetimer) {
                 window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
                 closetimer = null;
             }
         }

         // close layer when click-out
         document.onclick = mclose; 
    // -->
   </script>
```

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Why are you using `<!--` in your javascript?  You do not need that.

Comment: Where in your page is this script included?  In the `<head>` section?  In the start of middle of `<body>` section?  Or end of `<body>` section?  You may be trying to run code or reference DOM objects BEFORE they are ready to be used.

Comment: no there was not an error

Comment: @jFriend00 its in the head section

Comment: @jeroen I have used this code on a couple of sites and it works fine on a .html page. This is the first time I have tried to use it with a php page and it works in other browsers its just in chrome that nothing shows.

Comment: There should be no difference, the browser does not see any php, only the html / js generated by the php.

Comment: An experiment to try is to place this code at the end of the `<body>` section and see if you get different behavior.  The browser doesn't care what the extension of the browser page is (`.php` or `.html`), but you may get different loading timing with a `.php` page which could be affecting your code because it's in the `<head>` section yet trying to access the `document` object.

Comment: @jfriend00 Wouldn't that generate errors / messages in the console?

Comment: Remove the CDO and CDC (the opening and closing HTML comments). They were used back in the day to hide Javascript from browser that did not understand it. All browsers understand Javascript now, so it is not necessary. The problem *may* come from the fact that the closing HTML comment is commented out (`// -->`). Some browsers, Chrome in this case, may actually see it as a malformed HTML comment and then discard the Javascript inside.

Comment: @jfriend00 I placed the code at the bottom of the page just before the closing body tag and nothing. Would it matter that the tag is in a include file as well, ?php include 'inc/footer.php'; ?

Comment: I removed the html comments and still nothing.

Comment: You could try wrapping the script in a jquery $(document).ready() block to see if it's an issue with calling the elements before they're loaded.

Comment: @ZombieBunnies would that be wrapping each function in the .ready or just the whole script. Sorry kind of a noob when it comes to Javascript and jQuery

Comment: no problem.  The whole script.  It might not solve the problem, but it will ensure the script only fire when the DOM is loaded.  That being said, be sure to include a link to the jquery lib on you page if it isnt already.
< script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></ script> or whereever the lib is

Comment: @ZombieBunnies Tried that and still nothing

Comment: You're going to have to either share a link to the problem page or reproduce the issue in a jsFiddle and share that link.  Without being able to see your page, we can't do anything more than blind guesses which doesn't seem to be working so far.

Comment: @jfriend00 Here is the jFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/z5FZ5/. The links wont even show up like the footer links. Thanks all for your help so far.

Comment: That jsFiddle doesn't illustrate your situation (it's not using PHP includes and doesn't have the same sequence of loading and none of your code is being called) so it doesn't seem to be of any help.  Can you just share a link to your actual page that has the issue?

Comment: Opening the link in Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null` in Firefox: `TypeError: document.body is null` The console is the window you see when you press F12 and click on the console tab.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comments; your script is running and trying to get a canvas element in the head of the document. The canvas element does not exist at this point. You can wrap your script in a `$(document).ready(function(){your script here}` or place it just above the closing tag of body: `your script here</body>`

Your script includes google maps api but doesn't have a div with id of map_canvas.

Added `center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),` to the map_options variable

A bunch of script is commented out because of `<!--` uncommented that script.

After all that it still doesn't do much (not getting menu's in Firefox or Chrome or IE). Maybe it works in other browsers because they actually show you a cached version of the page. Try control + F5 to force reload it.

When you open the page and select view source, then save that in a html file. Add the following as the first child of header: `<base href="http://www.seadelightoceanfund.org/">` when you open that in any browser you should get the errors I got.